# Wordpress admin-bar is overlapping my content?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've struggled with this issue for a while and I've decided to ask if there is a more robust fix than what I currently have in place. I've seen many different fixes for this issue, some infinitely more complex than the next. But I don't see why it has to be so difficult?

I've tackled the issue with the following solution;

**HTML - (header.php)**

```
<div id="site-wrapper" class="<?php if ( is_admin_bar_showing() ) { echo 'admin-step'; } ?>">
    <!-- My site navigation -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.admin-step {
    margin-top: 32px !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 782px) {
    .admin-step {
        margin-top: 46px !important;
    }
}
```

> *Is there a real Wordpress solution to this issue?*
>
> *Or alternatively, is there a standardised way to correct this issue?*

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @SamJohnson Yes BS4 to be exact. :)

Comment: Have you seen this solution here? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116908/131918

Comment: I was looking at that last night, it seems insanely complex for a robust fix, strictly speaking in the size of the code.

Comment: I agree. Is it vital the bar appears for you rather than just hiding it? Personally I always hide it anyway, but each to their own!

Comment: I'll probably hide it after development, but for now the quick access to my cache controls is beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

The way i do for WordPress v5.6 is:

```html
<script>
if ($('#wpadminbar')[0])
        $('header').css('top', '32px')
</script>
```